# Where can I ask about PC OEM legislation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding legal matters that only apply to Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEMs) and am unsure where to ask.

It is off topic on [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and I don't have enough rep to chat yet.

Comment: Maybe https://law.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: sure https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5497/oem-legislation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not find any site within the SE network as a replacement for legal advice on your own specific case. First that needs a real lawyer and second any advice given from some stranger on the internet doesn't have any legal value.

If you're asking about legislation or procedures or professional that assist with your OEM related matters you could ask on [LAW.se](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Their help page about on-topic states this:

> In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals
>
> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter.

I really expect (and your [actual question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5497/oem-legislation) kind of reveals that) that your question falls in the last sentence. Your question seems to be seeking legal advice on a specific matter.

Law.se is in beta and a relative young site (about 6 months (2015-06-08)) so their definition of what can be answered and what is off-topic might not yet be clear enough defined. In all cases where there is doubt about a question being on-topic on a site, always post the specific question **FIRST** on the [meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/) of the site to verify the correct interpretation of their help center.